# How to strip a quote in a Cucumber Then-Step?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

i want to strip a quote in the following cucumber expression, but i get unknown step error

```
Then I should see "[\"20257\"]\n"
```

Cucumber suggested me this :(

```
Then /^I should see "([^"]*)"(\d+)\\"([^"]*)"$/ do |arg1, arg2, arg3|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

Any ideas, how to strip in this step?

Answer (score 2):

How about writing:

```
Then I should see "["20257"]\n"
```

With the step being:

```
Then /^I should see "(.*)"$/ do |txt|
  txt.gsub!('\n', "\n")
  # ...
end
```

Or you could use the multiline argument `"""` and not even have to worry about the `\n` substitution.